# Is there an equivalent of rospy.wait_for_message in ros2?

Tags: ros, ros2, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language. I have following line of code in my ROS1 project:

```
trajectory = rospy.wait_for_message('/trajectory_node_list', MarkerArray, 1.0)
```

How this line should look in ros2? I have find [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/378693/waitformessage-ros2-equivalent/) and [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/307370/ros2-whats-the-best-way-to-wait-for-a-new-message/) links with similar question but those two was about C++ and newest one was asked more than year ago, so maybe something changed from those time. Appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409214/is-there-an-equivalent-of-rospy.wait_for_message-in-ros2?/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-11-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not tried it, but I see that this features was added to rclpy Rolling just 2 days ago:

https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/issues/953

https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/pull/960

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2022-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-11-18**:
Thank you for your help. I'm working with Foxy for now, but it still a huge help. I'll check it.